# How to modify interpolation at end points for stacked area graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked area chart that I'm building using [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the end-points of my data to behave properly. Here's a screenshot showing the "issue" I'm seeing:

[image: Stacked area graph example]

The data associated with both the orange and dark blue segments start on the beginning of their corresponding months (February 1 and March 1, respectively). However, because the default interpolation mechanism "smooths" the curves, it appears as if non-zero values are present on days prior to the start of the month.

How can I get these end-points to drop vertically? I'm aware of the `step-before` and `step-after` interpolation models, but I like the look of the default chart. I simply want the ends to "behave" properly. Here's a mockup of what I envision it would look like:

[image: Modified graph mockup]

Is this kind of thing even possible?

Comment: You could insert a 0 data point just before the actual data starts, but it sounds like this is exactly what the step interpolations are meant for.

Comment: Would the package choke on having two data points on the same date (I assume the 0 value would be given the same starting date as the actual data)?

Comment: You'd need it just before the data starts, not on the exact same date. The latter may work as well depending on how exactly you're creating the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be complete, I ended up switching to the `step-` style interpolations for my graph, since it provides a more accurate picture of my data.